# File sharing from other app

Tags: android, share, android-gallery

I have one scenario for file sharing from other apps.
I want to get idea and solution if it's possible in android.

- Run myapp1(main app)
- Run gallery app and share one image to myapp2(it's another myapp inner gallery)
- save shared image in myapp2
- Automatically close myapp2 and return to myapp1 with some data

Please let me know if anything is confused.
Thanks for help

Comment: use https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid android:sharedUserId
    The name of a Linux user ID that will be shared with other applications. By default, Android assigns each application its own unique user ID. However, if this attribute is set to the same value for two or more applications, they will all share the same ID — provided that their certificate sets are identical. Applications with the same user ID can access each other's data and, if desired, run in the same process.

Comment: @AmodGokhale so my scenario is possible with sharedUserId?

Comment: yes ( As long as both apps are not yet published ), you can look for examples on net on similar lines. Do a basic POC before implementing a complete project.

Comment: @AmodGokhale myapp1 and myapp2 is same app but different process because another one is opened from gallery. your solution is still useful?

Comment: yes looks possible with hsaredUserId( sharing logic has to be implemented within both apps ), there are various other options given by Android - refer to this link https://developer.android.com/training/building-content-sharing.html